# How can I call an app scoped callback from the system_alert_window package

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-service

I am using the https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/system_alert_window and it starts a foreground service. This foreground service calls the following callback when a button click event happens in the system alert window.

This is my callback, it is a static method

```
  static Future<void> systemOverlayOnClickListner(String value) async {
    if (value == 'button_app_to_foreground') {
      await SystemAlertWindow.closeSystemWindow();
      await AppAvailability.launchApp('com.company_name.app_name');
    }
  }
```

This is the method in the plugin that registers the callback

```
  static Future<bool> registerOnClickListener(
      OnClickListener callBackFunction) async {
    final callBackDispatcher =
        PluginUtilities.getCallbackHandle(callbackDispatcher);
    final callBack = PluginUtilities.getCallbackHandle(callBackFunction);
    _channel.setMethodCallHandler((MethodCall call) {
      print("Got callback");
      switch (call.method) {
        case "callBack":
          dynamic arguments = call.arguments;
          if (arguments is List) {
            final type = arguments[0];
            if (type == "onClick") {
              final tag = arguments[1];
              callBackFunction(tag);
            }
          }
      }
      return null;
    });
    await _channel.invokeMethod("registerCallBackHandler",
        <dynamic>[callBackDispatcher.toRawHandle(), callBack.toRawHandle()]);
    return true;
  }
```

And this is the top level method that calls the callback

```
void callbackDispatcher() {
  // 1. Initialize MethodChannel used to communicate with the platform portion of the plugin
  const MethodChannel _backgroundChannel =
      const MethodChannel(Constants.BACKGROUND_CHANNEL);
  // 2. Setup internal state needed for MethodChannels.
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // 3. Listen for background events from the platform portion of the plugin.
  _backgroundChannel.setMethodCallHandler((MethodCall call) async {
    final args = call.arguments;
    // 3.1. Retrieve callback instance for handle.
    final Function callback = PluginUtilities.getCallbackFromHandle(
        CallbackHandle.fromRawHandle(args[0]));
    assert(callback != null);
    final type = args[1];
    if (type == "onClick") {
      final tag = args[2];
      // 3.2. Invoke callback.
      callback(tag);
    }
  });
}
```

But I get the following exception when trying to use a plugin method in the callback

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception:
> MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method launchApp on
> channel com.pichillilorenzo/flutter_appavailability)

From what I can see this is the problem. The registerOnClick listner will invoke a method channel. And this method channel will do the following

```
    case "registerCallBackHandler":
        try {
            List arguments = (List) call.arguments;
            if (arguments != null) {
                long callbackHandle = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(arguments.get(0)));
                long onClickHandle = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(arguments.get(1)));
                SharedPreferences preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREF_SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW, 0);
                preferences.edit().putLong(Constants.CALLBACK_HANDLE_KEY, callbackHandle)
                        .putLong(Constants.CODE_CALLBACK_HANDLE_KEY, onClickHandle).apply();
                startCallBackHandler(mContext);
                result.success(true);
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to register on click handler. Arguments are null");
                result.success(false);
            }
        }
```

So startcallback handler is being called

```
public static void startCallBackHandler(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREF_SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW, 0);
    long callBackHandle = preferences.getLong(Constants.CALLBACK_HANDLE_KEY, -1);
    Log.d(TAG, "onClickCallBackHandle " + callBackHandle);
    if (callBackHandle != -1) {
        FlutterMain.ensureInitializationComplete(context, null);
        String mAppBundlePath = FlutterMain.findAppBundlePath();
        FlutterCallbackInformation flutterCallback = FlutterCallbackInformation.lookupCallbackInformation(callBackHandle);
        if (sBackgroundFlutterView == null) {
            sBackgroundFlutterView = new FlutterNativeView(context, true);
            if(mAppBundlePath != null && !sIsIsolateRunning.get()){
                if (sPluginRegistrantCallback == null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Unable to start callBackHandle... as plugin is not registered");
                    return;
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Starting callBackHandle...");
                FlutterRunArguments args = new FlutterRunArguments();
                args.bundlePath = mAppBundlePath;
                args.entrypoint = flutterCallback.callbackName;
                args.libraryPath = flutterCallback.callbackLibraryPath;
                sBackgroundFlutterView.runFromBundle(args);
                sPluginRegistrantCallback.registerWith(sBackgroundFlutterView.getPluginRegistry());
                backgroundChannel = new MethodChannel(sBackgroundFlutterView, Constants.BACKGROUND_CHANNEL);
                sIsIsolateRunning.set(true);
            }
        }else {
            if(backgroundChannel == null){
                backgroundChannel = new MethodChannel(sBackgroundFlutterView, Constants.BACKGROUND_CHANNEL);
            }
            sIsIsolateRunning.set(true);
        }
    }
}
```

This appears to spawn a isolate to run the callback on. So when my callback is triiggered it will be triggered on a seperate isolate.

According to this post

[github post](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13937)

The only way to deal with this is to use the IsolateHandler plugin. But isn't this also a plugin again?

The desired behaviour is that I can call a plugin from the callback.

**Note: This happens with any plugin I try to call from the callback**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: 
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method launchApp on channel
com.pichillilorenzo/flutter_appavailability)
```

doesn't belong to [system alert window](https://pub.dev/packages/system_alert_window) plugin.

The reason why you are getting missing plugin exception is that, `flutter_appavailability` plugin doesn't support background execution.

So for this to work, you have to use isolate communications to bring the callback from `system_alert_window` to the main thread and then invoke this plugin. Which is mentioned [here](https://github.com/pvsvamsi/SystemAlertWindow#isolate-communication)

An easy way to identify, if a plugin supports background execution is, to see if it is required to register the plugin in `application.class` or `application.kt`

Comment: Hi, I tested this plugin in another project empty project and it works just fine, the same thing is happening when I try to call any other plugin from the callback

Comment: Only when using it in the callback it will fail. This is probably the reason why https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13937 I added further explanation to my post

Comment: Updated the answer, with explanation.